# Salesforce1 and Spring 14 Features

Tags: salesforce1-app, canvas, spring14

Do the currently available native Salesforce1 apps contain all the Spring 14 Release features?

This URL indicates that they are:
http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000188534

I'm noticing discrepencies between the web site at /one/one.app and the native apps.  After going through the steps to make the canvas app available, and using the “Signed Request (POST)” for the “Access Method” here is what I am seeing:

- For mobile browsers (Safari on iOS or Chrome on Android), it is shown
  and does POST the signed request to our server
- The Salesforce1 native
  app on **Android does not show the canvas app** in the navigation menu
- The Salesforce1 native app on **iOS shows the app in the navigation
  menu, but makes a GET request** to our server without the signed
  request

Apologies for the cross post but it didn't seem like I'd get any answers here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009wUiIAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay here.

I have confirmed the bugs for both the iOS and the Android native apps.  For iOS, the issue is that the app is incorrectly popping Canvas Apps out into a separate web container, which does a GET.  Instead, they should be opened inline which will do the correct signed request POST.  This issue should be fixed in the next release of the iOS app.

For Android, the feature is a bit behind in the dev and has not been implemented yet.  I am working with the Android team to get the Mobile Nav location implemented ASAP.

In the meantime, the easiest way will be to deploy using a VF page that uses the apex:canvasApp tag.

Again, sorry for the delay and the trouble.

Jay